# Spring Boot DBUnit test getting NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dbunit, spring-test-dbunit

I am trying to create a simple SpringBoot DB Unit repository test but I'm getting a:

> NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type
>   'example.ItemRepository'
>   available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

**My Gradle Dependencies**

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
runtime('com.h2database:h2')

testCompile("junit:junit")
testCompile("org.assertj:assertj-core:3.8.0")
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')

testCompile("org.dbunit:dbunit:2.4.9")
testCompile("com.github.springtestdbunit:spring-test-dbunit:1.0.0")
```

**My Repository** in `item-repository/src/main/java/example/ItemRepository`

```
@Component
public interface ItemRepository extends CrudRepository<Item, Long> {
}
```

**My Repository Test** in `item-repository/src/test/java/example/ItemRepositoryTest`

```
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
        TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class, DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = RepositoryTestConfiguration.class)
@DirtiesContext
public class ItemRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private ItemRepository repository;

    @Test
    @DatabaseSetup("Empty.xml")
    public void save() {
        // Given
        Item item = new Item

        // When
        Item response = repository.save(item);

        // Then
        assertThat(response.getId()).isNotNull();
    }

}
```

**My Test Configuration** in `item-repository/src/main/test/example/configuration/RepositoryTestConfiguration`

```
@Configuration
public class RepositoryTestConfiguration {
}
```

What do I need to include in my `RepositoryTestConfiguration` to get this to work?

Note: I keep my repositories in a seperate module to my `Application` class so I can't refer to that class in the test configuration

Comment: Where do you have `TestRepository`?

Comment: @AdamArold I added file paths to the titles of each. All the above files are in the `item-repository` module which is seperate to my `item-application` module which contains my `Application` class

Comment: Do you use the `@SpringBootApplication` and the `@ComponentScan` annotations?

Comment: @AdamArold I use `@SpringBootApplication` on my Application class, but I cant refer to that in my repository test due to dependency issues

Comment: Spring will only see your `RepositoryTestConfiguration` if it is a package which you included in your `@ComponentScan`

Comment: In my test I have the annotation `@ContextConfiguration(classes = RepositoryTestConfiguration.class)` which should specify where it is

Comment: In hindsight I dont think its anything to do with DBUnit, its purely a spring test configuration thing

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable jpa repository like following annotation:

@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.hop.repository"})

on your RepositoryTestConfiguration class then your repositories beans can be autowired.

Comment: I get `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!` If I do this

Answer (score 0):

Oh ok as you are using spring boot, it enables auto configurations. So just use @SpringApplicationConfiguration instead of @ContextConfiguration.

Comment: I dont seem to have SpringApplicationConfiguration on my classpath, do you know what library + version I need?